# set number to char of string and sum that number

Tags: java, android

for example :
i have an EditText that get string and want to convert every char of this String to the constant number and then sum all number of characters and save it on int variable.

Comment: if you don't know how to parse a string to int. Try on google, it should be the first answer.

Comment: fo example : apple is my string , set const number to a=10,p=20,l=8,e=4 then make and int like sum then  sum = 10+20+8+4 = 42

Comment: why a=10? p=20? Do you have a rule on this?

Comment: go throught you word and use a `switch/case` block to test your characters and sum coresponding int. That would be the easiest way for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define custom HashMap with char as key and int as value :

```
HashMap<Character,Integer> characterMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
characterMap.put('a',10);
characterMap.put('p',20);
characterMap.put('l',8);
characterMap.put('e',4);
```

Sum of each character value :

```
String data = "apple";
char[] charArray = data.toCharArray();
int total=0;
for(char ch : charArray){
   total+=characterMap.get(ch);
}
System.out.print("Total : "+total);
```

Answer (score 1):

should have googled a bit anyways:

```
    String s = "1234";
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String Str1 = new String("Your String");
  char[] Str2 = new char[The Size You want];
  Str1.getChars(0, str1.length(), Str2, 0);

           Now Str2 contains a set of characters you want. Give whatever values you can to your characters and parse it to int. Do the calculation thereafter.
```

Comment: special thanks but can you write that code for String like "apple" with this const number : a=10,p=20,l=8,e=4

Comment: maybe you could try to do it by yourself.

Comment: don't be a spoon fidder please. You are a developer.